# Android - findViewById does not work

Tags: android, listview

I am quite at a loss.

I have code in an Activity which is NOT the main Activity.

As follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    while (bsp <10)
    {
        list.add(bsp.toString());
        bsp++;
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_view);
    ListView view;
    view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.view);
```

However, the last line does not work:

```
view cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Does anyone have an idea?

As questioned, here the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.myapp.ViewActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<ListView
    android:id=”@+id/view″
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” >
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

or is there ANY other way to get the view?

Comment: please post your XML design

Comment: Why are you setting the content view of an `Activity` with an XML layout file called `fragment_view`? Also why do you emphasise that your `Activity` is *NOT* the main Activity?

Comment: Because in some other posts I read about this subject the user seemed to think this important. Also, most tutorials I dealt with work only in the main activity. However, when I put the xml-code into the activity_view instead of the fragment_view I have the same problem?

Comment: @why quotation mark of your listview is different than others?

Comment: Post that as an answer please....that actually did the trick....copy paste....-.-

Comment: i post it, thank you man !!

Comment: sry for voting so late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your quotation marks is strange and different from others try replace:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<ListView
    android:id=”@+id/view″
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” >
</ListView>
```

by

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of your layouts has a view with id `view` so the `R.id.view` does not resolve to a field in generated `R`.

Make sure the id you're trying to `findViewById()` is an id you've introduced in XML with e.g. `@+id/`.

For the `findViewById()` to return a non-null result, make sure the id is found in the layout you have as your content view, `layout/fragment_view.xml` in this case.

---

In the layout you posted you seem to have `@+id/view`. Clean and rebuild the project in case your generated `R` is an older, stale version.

Comment: Yes, try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: Well, after that, the class was basically all read, with the hint that I should import android.R, which did not change anything about there being suddenly a lot of mistakes. Second, The ListView in the XML now seems to be an invalid token. After nothing more then Clean. How can that be?

Comment: Possibly there's an error compiling your resources which prevents the `R` from being generated. If your IDE's errors tab doesn't show the resource build error, have a look at the build console tab.

Comment: Which folder should R be in?

Comment: `gen/your/package/name/R.java` for Eclipse/ADT; `.../build/generated/source/<config>/your/package/name/R.java` for Gradle-based builds.

Comment: fixed that one but stil having the same mistake - view is not a field, cannot be resolved